# Dynamically define springboot antmatcher for keycloak role

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I’ve known keycloak for a few days, it’s a very interesting tool. I am currently encountering a difficulty, perhaps due to my lack of experience. I am developing a java springboot application and I would like to define permissions based on user roles. I have created a realm, users, defined roles, created resources and permissions based on these roles. I have also used the permissions assessment tool to check the different permissions of different users.

Everything works fine when I define static routes in my KeycloakWebSecurityConfigureAdapt class, but I wish I could do something like this

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        super.configure(http);
        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry expressionInterceptUrlRegistry = http.cors() //
                .and()               
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests();
        for(String role : getRoles(KeycloakClientOrKeycloakRealm)) {
            for(String ressource : getAllowedRessourcesList(role)) {
                expressionInterceptUrlRegistry = expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.antMatchers(ressource).hasRole(role);
                
            }
       
        }
        expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated();
       
    }
```

any advice for getRoles(KeycloakClientOrKeycloakRealm) and getAllowedRessourcesList(role) functions? I thank you so much for taking the time to read

Comment: Hi do you still have problems with this one?

Comment: @dreamcrash when reading the keycloak documentation I realise that it is not really necessary to do this, it is possible to configure all permissions on keycloak directly. 
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_permission_overview
I'm still not sure about this so I haven't proposed a solution yet.

Comment: It is but bear in mind that it is much more complicated. If I were you in the beginning I would just use Keycloak for authenticate and leave the authorization part for your backend, using roles. I can post an example if you need help

Comment: Would it be easier to just add the annotation  hasRole in the endpoint that you want to apply the authorization ?

Comment: It would indeed be easier, but I would like an application whose rights would be configurable without redeploying it. I found a way to do this via keycloak policies enforcer but I still have some details to work out before publishing the solution.

Comment: Nice Let me know when you posted I am curious to see your solution